# Change of highlight color in UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbar, viber

I searched some pervious posts here said that changing the highlight color of UITabBar is not allowed by apple. But I found some new apps appear recently with different highlight color such as Viber.

If it is allowed, what code do i need in order to change the color?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 5 there's a selectedImageTintColor property on the tab bar

[UITabBar Class Reference - selectedImageTintColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/selectedImageTintColor)

Comment: Deprecated since iOS8.